# Bash move multiple subdirectory (including files) based on a list to a targe directory

Tags: linux, move, subdirectory

I have a directory that contains many subdirectories, each of which has several files.

But I only need some of the subdirectories (and the included files). And I have a list of the subdirectory names that I need to move.

How I do move the needed subdirectories to target directory based on the list in bash shell?

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code, and we'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean all subdirectories are moved to a single target directory, something like this should do it for you

```
cat subdirlist | xargs -i mv {} targetdir
```